# Faça um Programa que leia três números e mostre-os em ordem decrescente. Python

Tags: python, if

**Olá, estou tentando fazer um algoritmo que leia três números em Python e entregue eles de forma decrescente. O código está certo, mas sei que tem como escrever melhor somente usando lógica...**

```
a = float(input('Escreva um número: '))
b = float(input('Escreva um número: '))
c = float(input('Escreva um número: '))

if a >= b and a >= c and b >= c:
    print(f'A ordem decrescente é {a} , {b} e {c}')
elif a >= b and a >=c and c >= b:
    print(f'A ordem decrescente é {a} , {c} e {b}')
elif b >= a and b >= c and a >= c:
    print(f'A ordem decrescente é {b} , {a} e {c}')
elif b >= a and b >= c and c >= a:
    print(f'A ordem decrescente é {b} , {c} e {a}')
elif c >= a and c >= b and a >=b:
    print(f'A ordem decrescente é {c} , {a} e {b}')
elif c >= a and c >= b and b >= a:
    print(f'A ordem decrescente é {c} , {b} e {a}')
```

Escrevi este Algoritmo com base neste:

```
prod_1 = float(input('Valor 1° produto: '))
prod_2 = float(input('Valor 2° produto: '))
prod_3 = float(input('Valor 3° produto: '))

if prod_1 <= prod_2 and prod_1 <= prod_3:
    print('Compre o primeiro produto.')
elif prod_2 <= prod_3:
    print('Compre o segundo produto.')
else:
    print('Compre o terceiro produto')
```

Por isto não acho que precise usar listas e algo mais elaborado, seria somente para exercitar a lógica.

Mas acho que não é possível fazê-lo sem escrever muito código para uma tarefa esdrúxula.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, uma maneira diferente de resolver é utilizando `listas` e `for`.

segue um exemplo:

```
lista = []
qtd = 3
for i in range(qtd):
    elemento = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
    lista.append(elemento)

lista.sort(reverse = True) //ordena os elementos
print(lista)
```

Answer (score 2):

De forma geral, para uma quantidade qualquer de números, o mais simples é colocá-los em uma lista e ordená-la, como sugere a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/460738/112052).

Mas no caso específico de 3 números, e sem usar listas, você pode fazer assim:

```
if a < c:
    a, c = c, a

if a < b:
    a, b = b, a

if b < c:
    b, c = c, b

print(f'A ordem decrescente é {a}, {b} e {c}')
```

O primeiro `if` verifica se `a` é menor que `c`, e caso seja, [troco os valores deles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14836456) (`a` passa a ter o valor de `c`, e `c` passa a ter o valor de `a`). Ou seja, depois deste `if`, eu sei que `a` com certeza será maior ou igual a `c`.

Depois faço o mesmo com `b`, e depois do segundo `if` eu tenho certeza que `a` é maior ou igual a `b`. E como o primeiro `if` garantiu que `a` é maior ou igual a `c`, então neste ponto eu já sei que `a` é o maior de todos.

Então só falta verificar se `b` é menor que `c`, e caso seja, troco os valores deles. Assim, depois do terceiro `if`, com certeza `b` será maior ou igual a `c`.

Portanto, ao final destes três `if`'s, eu sei que `a`, `b` e `c` estarão em ordem decrescente.