# Definir o menor e o maior valor dentre três números

Tags: c#, lógica

[image: Print do formulário.][image: Este é o enunciado do exercício]

Estou tentando criar um programa em C# utilizando o windows forms onde ele recebe 3 números e me diz qual é o maior e qual é o menor, porém sou realmente muito iniciante e não acho onde está o erro, já verifiquei a lista de erros da IDE, porém, está vazia, é problema de lógica mesmo. O código funciona, mas de forma errada.

Segue meu código abaixo:

```
        double n1 = 0;
        double n2 = 0;
        double n3 = 0;

        n1 = double.Parse(txtb1.Text);
        n2 = double.Parse(txtb2.Text);
        n3 = double.Parse(txtb3.Text);

        if (n1 > n2 && n1 > n3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O maior número é: " + n1);
        }

        else if (n1 > n2 && n1 < n3)
        {

        }

        else if (n1 < n2 && n1 < n3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O menor número é: " + n1);
        }

        else if (n2 > n1 && n2 > n3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O maior número é: " + n2);
        }

        else if (n2 > n1 && n2 < n3)
        {

        }

        else if (n2 < n1 && n2 < n3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O menor numero é: " + n2);
        }

        else if (n3 > n1 && n3 > n2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O maior número é: " + n3);
        }

        else if (n3 > n1 && n3 < n2)
        {

        }

        else if (n3 < n1 && n3 < n2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O menor numero é: " + n3);
        }
```

Comment: "*funciona mas de forma errada*", como seria uma "forma errada" de funcionar? Quais valores você informou e qual foi o resultado? Percebi também que está usando o `else if` em todas as condições, então lembre-se que um `else if` só é executado se nenhuma condição anterior for satisfeita. No seu caso ele só exibirá uma mensagem por vez.

Comment: Eu coloco, por exemplo, 1, 5, 10 respectivamente porém ele sempre acusa que o primeiro numero é o maior ( no caso o 1) e não me diz qual é o menor

Comment: E se colocar 5, 1, 10, continua sendo o primeiro número?

Comment: sim, sempre o primeiro numero (se quiser coloco print do form)

Comment: Verifica se essas variaveis estâo renomeadas corretamente ```txtb1.Text```,  ```txtb2.Text```, ```txtb2.Text```.Testei com esse valores colocando direto nas variaveis ```n1```, ```n2```, ```n3``` e deu certo para os valores 1, 5, 10

Comment: Tem muito if e else aninhado e isso pode tornar difícil a verificação. Já tentou debugar o código? https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio#:~:text=Pressione%20F5%20para%20executar%20o,Start%20Debugging%20from%20the%20menu.

Comment: @BernardoLopes sim, estão, (n1, n2 e n3 são variaveis) (txtb 1, 2 e 3 são as textbox que recebem os valores

Comment: @GabrielSantana valeu cara vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Verifica os labels do textbox

Comment: ?? mas eles não tem influencia nenhuma no código... estão normais lá.

Comment: mas pode por exempo está no form tipo NUMERO 1 e apontar a variavel txtb3

Comment: não, estão todas em ordem...

Comment: Eu sugiro ir por partes. Primeiro vc tenta mostrar o maior e menor sem textbox (por exemplo, com valores fixos: `n1 = 1; n2 = 5; n3 = 10;`), pois da forma que está, não dá pra saber se o problema é na leitura dos dados ou no seu algoritmo (ou em uma combinação de ambos). Além disso, a informação que vc deu ("*sempre acusa que o primeiro numero é o maior*") não procede: [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/PHsmIA) um teste com 1, 5 e 10 (informa que 1 é menor) e [aqui](https://ideone.com/iyeXge) outro com 5, 1 e 10 (não imprime nada, pois cai em um dos `else if` vazios)

Comment: Aliás, pra que um `else if` vazio? Se não quer que nada seja feito em determinada condição, simplesmente não teste essa condição, que ela é naturalmente ignorada... Dito isso, se forem somente 3 números, não precisa desse monte de `if`/`else`, dá pra fazer de um jeito mais esperto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/460749/112052 (esse é em Python, mas não é difícil adaptar a ideia pra C#: https://ideone.com/Ahbm63) (claro que na prática, para ordenar vários números, é melhor usar o que já tem pronto na linguagem, como já sugerido nas respostas)

Answer (score 3):

Dá para fazer isso de forma muito simples, sem permitir erro se for digitado algo inválido. Eu só encerrei sem deixar dar erro, mas poderia ter feitoa algo mais como dar uma mensagem.

Eu vou fazer com `ReadLine()` no lugar do `TextBox` e o `WriteLine()` no lugar do `MessageBox()` para facilitar o teste, mas é só mudar.

A resposta mais votada não faz o que a pergunta pede. As outras são interessantes, eu poderia ser feito algo parecido, mas não acredito que o intuito não seria usar recursos prontos, ou pior ainda, de forma ineficiente como duas são.

```
using static System.Console;
                    
if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var n1)) return;
if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var n2)) return;
if (!double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var n3)) return;
double menor = n1;
double maior = n1;
if (n2 > maior) maior = n2;
if (n3 > maior) maior = n3;
if (n2 < menor) menor = n2;
if (n3 < menor) menor = n3;
WriteLine($"O maior número é: {maior} e o menor número é: {menor}");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/P9OivW). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jgzgnv). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/GreaterLesser.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente, seu programa precisa exibir **o menor e o maior valor inseridos pelo usuário**. Creio que uma abordagem simples seria criar um vetor (`double[]`) com os três números inseridos e utilizar os métodos `Min()` e `Max()`, disponíveis no [namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/) `System.Linq`. Os métodos que mencionei estão disponíveis para coleções que implementam a interface `IEnumerable`; retornam o menor e o maior valor dentro de uma coleção, respectivamente.

No começo do seu arquivo, insira o uso do namespace mencionado para ter acesso aos métodos:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Assim você pode apenas chamar o método `MessageBox.Show` diretamente, sem a necessidade de verificar qual número é maior/menor ou ter que ordenar uma lista para tal, por exemplo:

```
// criando um vetor de tamanho fixo, dado que precisa comparar apenas três números
double[] valoresInseridos = new double[3] { n1, n2, n3 };

MessageBox.Show($"Menor valor: {valoresInseridos.Min()}");
MessageBox.Show($"Maior valor: {valoresInseridos.Max()}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi o seu problema pelos seus comentários é que seu programa só exibe o maior ou só o menor e não os dois ao mesmo tempo.

Isso se deve ao fato de que ao usar `if` com vários `else if` somente o primeiro deles cuja condição for verdadeira será executado. No seu caso, mais de um `else if` avalia como verdadeiro (um para o maior número e outra para o menor). Uma primeira alternativa é colocar tudo como `if` já que você fez todas as combinações possíveis.

Outra opção é usar as biblioteca `Math` com os métodos `Max`e `Min`. Assim substituindo todo seu bloco `if` por:

```
MessageBox.Show("O maior número é: " + Math.Max(n1,Math.Max(n2,n3)));
MessageBox.Show("O menor numero é: " + Math.Min(n1,Math.Min(n2,n3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   double n1, n2, n3;

    n1 = double.Parse(txtb1.Text);
    n2 = double.Parse(txtb2.Text);
    n3 = double.Parse(txtb3.Text);

        if (n1 > n2 && n1 > n3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O maior número é: " + n1);
            if (n2 > n3) { MessageBox.Show("O menor número é: " + n3); } else { MessageBox.Show("O menor número é: " + n2); }

        }else
        {
            if (n2 > n1 && n2 > n3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O maior número é: " + n2);
                if (n1 > n3) { MessageBox.Show("O menor número é: " + n3); } else { MessageBox.Show("O menor número é: " + n1); }
            }

            else
            {                     
              MessageBox.Show("O maior número é: " + n3);
                if (n2 > n1) { MessageBox.Show("O menor número é: " + n1); } else { MessageBox.Show("O menor número é: " + n2); }
            }
        }
```

Fiz assim por ser uma comparação pequena entre 3 numeros, caso tenha mais numeros o recomendado é usar a classe Math com os metodos Min e Max. a seguir deixarei o link para a leitura da documentação sobre a classe, caso tenha interesse em saber mais.
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.math?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode usar uma lista e ordena-la, porém é **muito mais lento** dependendo do caso do que comparar com os operadores de comparação.

```
// Declarando a lista
List<double> lista = new List<double>();

// Adicionando os valores à lista
lista.Add(double.Parse(txtb1.Text));
lista.Add(double.Parse(txtb2.Text));
lista.Add(double.Parse(txtb3.Text));

// Ordenando em ordem crescente
lista.Sort();

// Pegando o menor e o maior valor
double menor = lista[0]; // O primeiro da lista
double maior = lista[lista.Count - 1] // O último da lista
```